# What can this font be?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

So, we've tried `https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont` and it's forums, and many other tools like `https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator`, and we're finally here.

For the love of God does anyone have any idea what font this is?

This is how it was sent to us. It's been almost a week of searching, and we haven't been able to find one like this.

[image]

Comment: Tried that, tried every font on canva, posted on forums, heard about this forum and finally posted here :-)

Comment: Tried my best but couldn't find it.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about these images? Where did you see them, do you have more samples, do you know anything about the technology used to print them? I'm not sure they're professionally designed, though, that unbalanced 's' that seems upside down feels like the work of someone who is not a specialist font designer.

Comment: They were sent just the way they've been posted. Sadly, none of the fonts mentioned in the answers match. The serifs on the n, u and s are really unique.

Answer (score 3):

It looks vaguely like some "inscriptional" fonts of the twentieth century intended to have a slightly "monumental" feel. For example the letters are very wide and quite monoline and the 'b' symmetrical to a 'd'. Closest I've found are [Lovato](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lovato) by Philatype and [Quattrocento Roman](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/quattrocento-roman) by Impallari. [Latinia](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Latinia) is similar, so is Luxury Text by Christian Schwartz. It's not a typewriter face: those are monospaced and much less sculpted. Nebiolo did a few fonts like this in the 1920s-1950s period.

Giving us some idea where you found these images would be good, so we can see if there are more samples of the text to be found. More characters are always useful in font identification.

Answer (score 1):

I searched all relevant Google fonts, all Sans-serif and Typewriter fonts on `dafont.com` and some font matching websites, but I couldn't find this font. It's possible that I might have skipped it by mistake, but that's less likely.

Not saying it can't be found or doesn't exist on these sites, but looks like it's a bit uncommon.

I am sharing a few somewhat similar fonts (there are obvious differences but some similarities also exist) you may want to have a look, in case you or other users can't manage to find the exact one:

**From** `myfonts.com`

*Pueblito Light*

[image]

---

**From** `Dafont.com`:

*F25 Executive*
[image]

*Made Waffle Slab*
[image]

---

**From Google fonts:**

*Corben*
[image]

*Scope One*
[image]

*Cutive*
[image]

---

*If you want to download, please check whether they are free to use / their licenses / pricing etc. Google fonts mentioned are free btw.*

In case you want to search extensively again, I suggest focus on letters like **w**, **g**, **a**, **u**, **f** and **s**. I think it would be easy to filter things.

Answer (score 0):

Posted this in wrong area prior - looks like Cooper Lt BT to me:

https://blogfonts.com/cooper-lt-bt.font

As mentioned above, tried to focus primarily on the g and a letters first.